# Как заменить элемент в DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

```
$html = '<a href="/111/" class="elt zi2" title="Ston" target="_blank">Star</a>
текст
<a href="/3233/" class="elt zi2" title="Ston" target="_blank">Star</a>';

if($html) {
    ($dom = new DOMDocument)->loadHTML($html);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $el) {
        $dom->replaceChild('2222222222222', $el);        
    }
print_r($html);
}
```

Перебираю ссылки в цикле, вопрос в том, как заменить ссылку скажем на текст?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для первого аргумента в replaceChild нужен объект DOMNode, для текста это будет DOMText, его можно создать методом [createTextNode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.createtextnode.php)

```php
<?php
$html = '<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head><body>
<a href="/111/" class="elt zi2" title="Ston" target="_blank">Star</a>
текст
<a href="/3233/" class="elt zi2" title="Ston" target="_blank">Star</a></body></html>';

if ($html) {
    ($dom = new DOMDocument)->loadHTML($html);
    $xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $ns = $xp->query('//a');
    foreach ($ns as $el) {
        $el->parentNode->replaceChild($dom->createTextNode('2222222222222'), $el);
    }
    print_r($dom->saveHTML());
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught DOMException: Not Found Error in /adr.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /adr.php(14): DOMNode->replaceChild(Object(DOMText), Object(DOMElement)) #1 {main} thrown in /adr.php on line 14

Comment: Что та ошибку выдает

Comment: Подправил решение, ошибка была в том, что replaceChild надо вызывать непосредственно на родителе элемента. Добавил указание кодировки в HTML иначе она ломается при сохранении и ссылки ищу с помощью XPath, а то методы DOM - это боль.

Comment: К примеру переменная содержит $html = '    ';, выдает ошибку, условие пропускает. Какие есть варианты еще кроме try { }, возможно переменная содержит какие та другие символы. Что так же выдает ошибку. В целом есть какое универсальное решение для php 8.0

Comment: В случае ошибки loadHTML вернет false. Несмотря на то, что некорректный HTML обычно успешно загружается, данная функция может генерировать ошибки уровня E_WARNING при обнаружении плохой разметки. Для обработки данных ошибок можно воспользоваться функциями обработки ошибок libxml. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php